# Using a cell reference cycle (of a range) to open and print excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, printing

I'm looking to go through a range of cells and use each value within the cells to open a workbook, to then print out the first worksheet, close the workbook, and then cycle to the next value until the range hits a blank cell.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Test()

Dim varCellvalue As Long
Dim rng As Range, rngcell As Range
Dim wb As Long
Set rng = Range("A1:A20")

For Each cell In rng

If Not cell = "" Then

varCellvalue = Range(cell).Value

Workbooks.Open "G:\_QA\Excel Workspace\Projects\Auto-print Processing Forms\Printouts\" & varCellvalue & ".xls"

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False

Workbooks(varCellvalue).Close SaveChanges:=False

On Error Resume Next

End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

I have a workbook that processes data of another imported sheet that gets updated every day. So far I'm to the point of having all the information I need to then cycle through the generated list and use the resulting cell values to then open and print the worksheets I need.

Edit:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, rngcell As Range
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set rng = Range("A1:A20")

For Each rngcell In rng.cells

    If Not rngcell.value = "" Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\_QA\Excel Workspace\Projects\Auto-print Processing Forms\Printouts\" & rngcell.Value & ".xls")

        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False


    End If

Next rngcell

End Sub
```

Comment: You don’t need range(cell).value, cell.value should do it for you

Comment: My macro then gives back a mismatch error?

Comment: Also, unless all your spreadsheets will alway be numbers, I wouldn’t make varcellvalue a long.  I don’t think you even need it, you can just use cell.value throughout.  wb should be an Excel.workbook, not a long.

Comment: Crap, one more, use.  Set wb = workbooks.open(... etc then wb.selected... and wb.close

Comment: Ok, not done yet. It is bad form to use a reserved word as a variable, cell should have a different spelling, maybe rngCell?  I believe you might want to do something like “for each rngCell in rng.cells”, not quite as confident there.

Comment: Okay so here's the edits I've done so far (See above edit)

Comment: the wb = Workbooks.open(...) however keeps giving back a Object variable or With block variable not set error
But it's opening the file I need it to?

Comment: Make it `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("...` as commented by @wallyeye. Also check if the path is correct and  mgCell content does not have any leading or trailing white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Print From Range

### The Code

```
Sub PrintFromRange()

  Const cPath As String = "G:\_QA\Excel Workspace\Projects\" _
      & "Auto-print Processing Forms\Printouts\"
  Const cExt As String = ".xls"
  Const cRng As String = "A1:A20"

  Dim i As Integer

  With Range(cRng)
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
      If .Cells(i, .Column) <> "" Then
        With Workbooks.Open(cPath & .Cells(i, .Column) & cExt)
          .ActiveSheet.PrintOut Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
          .Close False
        End With
'       Else: Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

### Remarks

The code demonstrates that sometimes there is no need for using object references.

Using the `With` statement is a good way to section the code i.e. make it shorter and more readable.

It is unclear to me why using `Not` and `=` could be preferable to using `<>`. In this way I use it exclusively for objects, usually `If Not ... Is Nothing Then`.

The `PrintOut`'s property `Copies` is by default 1, so it can safely be omitted. It is unclear what the default value of `Collate` is, and my Excel 2003 doesn't recognize `IgnorePrintAreas`.

The first argument of `Close` is `SaveChanges` so it can be simplified by just 'adding' its parameter (`False` in this case).

By not using the lines `Else: Exit For` you allow the range to be non-contiguous i.e. when the code 'hits' an empty cell it still searches in the following cells of the range which might be even preferable in this case since you have declared a small range. In many other cases you might not want to forget to include those lines.